# Docker containers not accessible from internet (using jwilder's nginx+letsencrypt solution)

Tags: nginx, docker, lets-encrypt

I have been using the jwilder's nginx + letsencrypt solution to access my containers online.

Last week my server crashed and after a restart, I couldn't access any of my containers from the internet. Accessing them from LAN works but I get "refused to connect" errors when I use the web address (I'm using DDNS with a domain I own).

Checking the logs, I immediately saw errors in letsencrypt logs like: :Verify error:: Fetching http:///.well-known/acme-challenge/oSGmRMyB-df4XEN3ZW-8ksBvtxxO8m2Di50mhpWWuu8: Connection refused

I have already double checked port forwarding on my Router and things seem to be ok. I can even use port 22 to SSH into my machine, just to validate that the port forwarding is working.

I also checked UFW status, thinking of firewall issues on my server and UFW is inactive as well.

Any suggestions on how can I debug this further?

**Edit**: I did an nmap on my server's local IP. I can see that all the container ports are open but the nginx ports 80 and 443 are closed. I'm now at a loss how to ensure the nginx docker container can open this port. Here's my docker-compose :

```
services:
  nginx:
    image: jwilder/nginx-proxy:latest
    container_name: nginx
    restart: always
    labels:
      com.github.jrcs.letsencrypt_nginx_proxy_companion.nginx_proxy: 'true'
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
    volumes:
      - ./data//htpasswd:/etc/nginx/htpasswd
      - ./data/certs:/etc/nginx/certs:ro
      - ./data/conf.d:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - ./data/vhost.d:/etc/nginx/vhost.d
      - ./data/html:/usr/share/nginx/html
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro
    networks:
      - proxy

  letsencrypt:
    image: jrcs/letsencrypt-nginx-proxy-companion:latest
    container_name: letsencrypt_multi
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./data/vhost.d:/etc/nginx/vhost.d
      - ./data/certs:/etc/nginx/certs:rw
      - ./data/html:/usr/share/nginx/html
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro
    depends_on:
      - nginx
    networks:
      - proxy

networks:
  proxy:
    driver: bridge
```

Answer (score 0):

If someone else is facing the issue, I found the solution.

In one of my containers that I was exposing through the nginx reverse proxy, I had commented out the "VIRTUAL_HOST" environment variable to stop internet access to the container. I had however, forgotten to comment out "VIRTUAL_PORT" and this was leading to errors in the default.conf for nginx. When I restarted nginx, I was getting parse errors for default.conf
`invalid number of arguments in "upstream" directive`

The offending entry was pointing to the container which had the above mentioned misconfiguration, fixing that and restarting the container and subsequently nginx resolved the problem for me.